# How to restore deleted Office 365 groups

Tags: office365, restore

My Office365 group was deleted inadvertently. Is there any way to restore it?
There are important data and documents in it!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Get-AzureADMSDeletedGroup` to display all deleted Office 365 groups in your tenant that are still available to restore.

Also, you could use `Get-AzureADMSDeletedGroup –Id <objectId>` to verify the specific deleted group has not yet been permanently purged.

Once you have verified that the group is still available to restore, you could use `Restore-AzureADMSDeletedDirectoryObject –Id <objectId>` 
to restore the group and its contents.

If the group contains documents, SP sites, or other persistent objects, it might take up to 24 hours to fully restore a group and its contents.

Please refer to the official document:
[Restore a deleted Office 365 group in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-restore-deleted)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

We can use `Restore-AzureADMSDeletedDirectoryObject –Id <objectId>` cmd in Azure Active Directory PowerShell module to restore the O365 group.

Here is a reference article: [Restore a deleted Office 365 Group](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restore-a-deleted-Office-365-Group-b7c66b59-657a-4e1a-8aa0-8163b1f4eb54)

Hope it will help those who have the same issues.

Besides, I find a O365&Azure support channel called [Dev Chat](https://aka.ms/devchat) where I found the answer to this question. It's a free service for Microsoft partner.